# Is there a keyboard shortcut to open a bookmark from the Bookmarks Bar on Chrome for Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, osx-mountain-lion

Tabbing from the Location/Search "Omnibar" will bring focus to individual items in the Bookmarks Bar, but no variation of Return, Enter and meta-keys seems to open them.

Is there any way to trigger a fake click on a specific bookmark (or extension) using only the keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Windows](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157179), you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to set the focus to the browser toolbar, navigate to the option that you wish to activate (including bookmark) and active it using <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Unfortunately, [no such option exist in Mac](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165450&topic=25799&ctx=topic), as of now.

Answer (score -2):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>

[Google is your friend.](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165450)

Comment: I'm not looking for how to open the bookmarks manager; I'm looking for how to open a specific bookmark item highlighted in the bookmarks bar, below the OmniBar. Edited for clarity.